Backslash escape characters in zsh string for use as a path argument
In zsh, what is the most efficient and/or most concise way to backslash escape characters in a string for use as a path argument?
I do not want to enclose the whole path in any type of quotes.
e.g., if I have a zsh string a & b, I want to get a\ \&\ b.
I do not want: 'a & b', "a & b", $'a & b', etc. (those can be obtained via various q parameter expansion flags; none of the q flags that I found backslash escape spaces or ampersands, so they won't work for me)
I haven't been able to find a way to do this concisely, either via parameter expansion or via any other simple command, other than to use a regex replace parameter expansion (of the form ${name//pattern/repl}), but that would require me to learn all the characters that must be escaped, and would require me to update the expansion if there are any changes.

In a quick test, this appeared to produce the desired result: print -r -- ${(q):-a & b}  printed a\ \&\ b.  However, I don't know if it would work in all contexts.

@Gairfowl I already tried (q), but I didn't include the -r option for print. Thanks.

I'm not sure to understand the purpose; If you already have a string in a var then you don't need to do anything for using it as a path

What's the use case here? It sounds like you are attempting to build a flat string to use as a list of arguments, rather than simply using an array.

@Fravadona @chepner: I want to use brace expansion in a single argument, which doesn't appear to work when quoted with '…', "…", or $'…'.

So you're trying to eval a string? There might exist netter ways

@Fravadona I'm trying to do the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78614085/zsh-brace-expansion-for-argument-containing-spaces-supplied-from-a-variable

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to expand {1,2} from a variable without eval. aside: you can expand a glob stored in var with ${~var}
