zsh brace expansion for argument containing spaces supplied from a variable
In zsh, how can I use brace expansion for an argument containing spaces supplied from a variable?
e.g., I want to rename a file from ~/a b/1.txt to ~/a b/2.txt.
I can do this manually from the command line using brace expansion (but without using a variable) by backslash escaping the space and by not quoting the brace expansion path, via:
mv ~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt

None of the following work:
mv '~/a b/{1,2}.txt'

mv "~/a b/{1,2}.txt"

mv $'~/a b/{1,2}.txt'

mv '~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt'

mv "~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt"

mv $'~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt'

I want to be able to do this with the value of a variable, like:
bep='~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt'
set -x
mv "${bep}"
mv ${bep}
mv $bep
set +x

But this doesn't work.
zsh reports (because of set -x) that the command that is run is:
mv '~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt'

Neither changing the quotes for, nor removing the backslash from escaping the space in, bep='~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt' changes anything.
Neither the (Q) nor the any of the (q) parameter expansion flags seem to help.
I assume that I should be trying to prevent zsh from surrounding the argument with single quotes, but I don't know how to do that concisely.
Or maybe there's some way to enable brace expansion from within single quotes.
Or…

brace expansion happens before parameter expansion and tilde expansion. You can force tilde expansion to be done after parameter expasion, but brace expansion still wouldn't work.

A correct command would be mv ~/'a b'/{1,2}.txt, quoting only the segment that requires quote. (In the extreme, only the space needs to be escaped, but IMO quoting the entire segment looks better.) You could store the resulting arguments in an array: bep=(~/'a b'/{1,2}.txt); mv "${bep[@]}" would do the trick without any additional zsh-specific expansions.

is something along the below what you are attempting to do ?
touch a\ b/1.txt
mv a\ b/{1,2}.txt
mv a\ b/{2,1}.txt

ll -r a\ b
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 tick talkies   0 12 Jun 18:51 1.txt
drwxr-xr-x  3 tick talkies  96 12 Jun 18:51 .. 
drwxr-xr-x  3 tick talkies  96 12 Jun 18:53 .

beb='mv a\ b/{1,2}.txt'

eval $beb     

ll a\ b/2.txt    
-rw-r--r--  1 tick talkies  0 12 Jun 18:51 a b/2.txt

NB: the use of eval is generally frowned upon as possible injection of dodgy commands , if however you are in full control then its less so.
as always, test/check/double-check all code offered/shown

eval … works, but, if possible, I'd prefer to do something more secure / more concise / more zsh idiomatic. I would imagine that there's a parameter expansion flag, a parameter expansion, a setting, or something else that somehow outputs the value of a variable without enclosing it in single quotes, or some way to get brace expansion to work from within single quotes. If no one provides a better answer in a week or so, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

There's apparently no way to process a brace expansion in a variable other than eval, but you may be able to avoid the issue by storing the arguments for mv in an array. Using arrays for this is usually a good practice anyway:
> bep=(~/a\ b/{1,2}.txt)
> typeset -p bep  # typeset -p is a good way to see what's in a variable
typeset -a bep=( '/Users/me/a b/1.txt' '/Users/me/a b/2.txt' )
> ls -l ~/a\ b/*
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 12 21:38 1.txt
> mv $bep
> ls -l ~/a\ b/*
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 12 21:38 2.txt

Other forms of quoting will also work:
> ar=('~/a b/'{1,2}.txt)
> typeset -p ar
typeset -a ar=( '~/a b/1.txt' '~/a b/2.txt' )
> print -r -- $ar
~/a b/1.txt ~/a b/2.txt
> print -r -- ${~ar}
/Users/me/a b/1.txt /Users/me/a b/2.txt

The ${^...} expansion behaves like a brace expansion. If the source values that were in the brace expansion can be in an array, this is an option:
> sv=(1 2)
> ar=(~/a\ b/${^sv}.txt)
> typeset -p ar
typeset -a ar=( '/Users/me/a b/1.txt' '/Users/me/a b/2.txt' )

If the brace expansion is required, the ${^...} expansion can be used to limit what is passed to the eval command:
> be=`{1,2}` 
> ar=(~/a\ b/${^$(eval print -r -- $be)}.txt)
> typeset -p ar
typeset -a ar=( '/Users/me/a b/1.txt' '/Users/me/a b/2.txt' )


The zmv utility may work better for the general problem of building before-and-after filenames. By default it calls mv, but it can be used with almost any command. This example will increment numbers in a set of filenames:
> autoload zmv   # can be in ~/.zshrc
> ls f*
f1.txt  f22.txt
> zmv '(f)(<->)(.txt)' '${1}$((${2}+1))${3}'
> ls f*
f2.txt  f23.txt


wrt to '...no way to process a brace expansion in a variable other than eval...'
assigning the definition to an alias is one potential (can't say it fits all scenarios):
alias beb='mv a\ b/{1,2}.txt'
then, simply invoke that
beb
i've also seen (probaby used)
echo 'mv a\ b/{1,2}.txt' > /tmp/beb.cmd
source /tmp/beb.cmd

@ticktalk - wow - cool techniques; never thought of using an alias that way before. However, for our purposes here I think we can categorize them as "eval without using eval", with many of the same tradeoffs.

eval works better for my purposes for various reasons, but thanks for the suggestion. It will be useful in other circumstances.
